# Fail to understand the saftey of axios requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

I currently fail to understand the safety behind Axios requests.

**Example**
I have a simple button to register a user with a random string through a post request.
This post request is then sent to my express server which then adds this user to my MongoDB.
 What stops someone from just opening some third-party API tool like https://reqbin.com/ and spam creating users with this post request.

**Another Example**
I have a chat, every time you send a message an insert request is sent to my express server through an axios post request. Again, what stops someone from using some third-party API tool to spam requests to create tons of messages?

Comment: Nothing. This has nothing to do with Axios, this is just what it means to host a web server on the public internet. You want anyone be able to become a user, and want to accept requests from any client. Distinguishing good ones from spam is hard, and there is no silver bullet. (Though for your chat, you'd require a login probably - which still has the problem that anyone can sign up)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [CSRF protection](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html), [captcha verification](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/), [rate users' request limit](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/express+too+many+requests) and even block the users' IP via firewall automatically if they sent you WAY too many requests in a short span of time (likely to be a bot). Even then you shouldn't trust any data before validation and sanitization.

In the end you can only rely on the backend policies, routines and data to keep everything safe and running.